# How to get 10 closest locations from table

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, closest-points, mysql-select-db

I want to get 10 closest locations with longitude and latitude. I store longitude and latitude as double. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM company as dest where 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs( dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 – dest.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis <10 and ORDER BY dis limit 10;
```

but I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– dest.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis <10 and ORDER BY dis limit 10 ' at line 1
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: theres an extra bracket `)` in it.. find it out

Comment: @AhmedZ. then the error would not be there.

Comment: there 16 bracket open and 16 bracket close !

Comment: not yet find miss bracket now !

Comment: I add already, now I get this error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'POWER'

Comment: I delete 1 close bracket: SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - (dest.longitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest where dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10;

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'dis' in 'where clause'

Comment: 1. Latitudes are in the range +-90 degrees.  You are doing 122.4058 - dest.latitude.  122.4058 is not a valid latitude.  2. You are using round earth equations for distance.  Are the lat/lon pairs really 1,000 of miles apart?  If not, you can use the much simpler flat earth equations to get distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
     POWER(SIN((37.7907 – abs(dest.longitude))
```

EDIT2:

```
     SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - abs(dest.longitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest HAVING dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10;
```

Comment: I add already, but I get this error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'POWER'

Comment: I change to like this : SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - (dest.longitude)) * pi()/180 / 2)), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest where dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10;

Comment: i think maybe you mean `abs(dest.longitude)`

Comment: I store as double , but if I select , so it may be string !

Comment: now I change to this: SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - (dest.longitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest where dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10;

Comment: and I get this error : #1054 - Unknown column 'dis' in 'where clause'

Comment: in your previous error unkown dis in where clause try to replace WHERE by HAVING

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0006 sec )

Comment: I have 24 rows in company table, but why it is empty ?

Comment: still empty result, I don't know why !

Comment: did the result returns if you remove this `HAVING dis <10` ?

Comment: nice :) , then your results was greater then 10 :)

Comment: but I also get 2 rows that doesn't have latitude and longitude.

Comment: what condition I have to set in order to not get rows without lat or long ?

Comment: I want to get only companies that have latitude and longitude !

Comment: i guess something like : where lat <> 0 or long <> 0

Comment: because i didnt see your table structure thats why i guessed

Comment: or like that if empty , where lat is not null

Comment: it shows error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where dest.longitude is not null and dest.latitude is not null' at line 1

Comment: when I use :      SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - abs(dest.longitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest ORDER BY dis limit 10 where dest.longitude is not null and dest.latitude is not null;

Comment: and if you want make dis < 10 , then should be like that : from ... where ... having dis < 10 order by ...

Comment: I don't know why I use having dis < 10, I take this formular from others ! \

Comment: this because you will get all results < 10 , but your results are all > 10 then maybe you will change 10 to 15 or 20 or something you want get results < then it . if you dont want filter your result then you dont need having dis < 10

Comment: where should I put having dis < 20 ? I have errors when I use it ! the result I get before seems not right because I put the nearest place from companyID 1 to 10, I get random companyID like 1, 4, 20 , ...

Comment: now I can get the nearest places to my current locations by using this query: SELECT
companyID,relevantTextName as companyName,
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( dest.latitude ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( 11.576150037278605 ) ) + COS( RADIANS(  dest.latitude ) )
* COS( RADIANS( 11.576150037278605 )) * COS( RADIANS( dest.longitude ) - RADIANS( 104.89529371261597  )) ) * 6380 AS distance
FROM company as dest
having distance < 10
ORDER BY distance limit 10;

Comment: But it is not dynamically !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922404/how-to-efficiently-find-the-closest-locations-nearby-a-given-location     this may help you about location , i dont understand what you mean by its not dinamically

Answer (score 1):

I copied your sql-code and put it into an editor having syntax-highlight support (Sublime2) and the character, the error points to (looking like a minus) actually is another sign ..

According to this webpage this character is called EN DASH (you see it in utf8-hex-code at the end of the link :))
http://www.utf8-character.info/#!%E2%80%93

Try to replace this character by a simple minus.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10' at line 1

Comment: @smartgirl, remove the "as dis" ... I think you can't use aliases there. If you need this as a result, you'd have to write this heavy calculation in the select-part of the query.

Comment: I change to like this: SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((122.4058 - abs( dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(122.4058 * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((37.7907 - dest.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2)), 2) )) as dis FROM company as dest where dis <10 ORDER BY dis limit 10;

Comment: but I get this error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'POWER'