# Efficient way to query multiple Google Routes?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is a (logical?) extension to a problem which has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922404/how-to-efficiently-find-the-closest-locations-nearby-a-given-location), and for which Google also provide [example code for](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) (as a side, I'm impressed with the elegance of a single SQL query).  In my case, however, I don't want distances as the crow flies, but distances given by a route finder.  This has relevance in areas with large geographical features (such as estuaries) inhibiting travel between 2 very close locations [1].

At the moment, I have *n* stores; when a user enters their location (*p* postcode, converted to lat/long), I call the routes API *n* times, then sort the results by distance on the fly with javascript, and return the 5 closest to the user. Is there an efficient way to get the results from the API without doing *n* calls? This would help by:

- preventing a (relatively) large amount of my quota being used each time *each* person uses my finder
- speeding up the time I can return results to users because I'm not doing *n* API calls

[1] Even some large companies get caught out by this; Calshot to Warsash, by car, is a distance of [29 miles](http://goo.gl/maps/2R7OA). However, using [Tesco's Store Finder](http://www.tesco.com/store-locator/uk/), and entering your location as Calshot, shows the Warsash store to be the 2nd closest, at 3.73 miles away

Comment: Have you looked at the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)?  The usual suggestion is to reduce the number of candidate locations with the "as the crow flies" distance, the refine those using the distance matrix to sort by actual driving distance.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I'd completely missed that in the docs!