# mysql suggest start and end nearest locations

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table `locations` (`id`, `name`, `latitude`, `longitude`) and another table `loads` (`id`,`from_location_id`, `to_location_id`).

On my php form I get the id for from_location and the id for to_location.

How can I suggest the loads near from_location that should be delivered near to_location (with a range about 100km on both start and and locations)?

Thank you!

EDIT

```
SELECT locations.id,
       SQRT( POW(111.2 * (latitude1 - {$from_coordinates['latitude']}), 2) + POW(111.2 * ({$from_coordinates['longitude']} - longitude1) * COS(latitude1 / 57.3), 2)) AS distance,
       loads.id
FROM locations
INNER JOIN loads ON loads.from_location = locations.id
HAVING distance < 100
ORDER BY distance
DESC LIMIT 5
```

The problem is that I don't know how to find loads that start from this region and should be delivered near the latitude and longitude of another location id. I'm begginer on stackoverflow, sorry for any inconveniece

Comment: a `select` query, perhaps? show what you've attempted so far - we're not here  to do your job for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently find the closest locations nearby a given location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922404/how-to-efficiently-find-the-closest-locations-nearby-a-given-location)

Comment: SELECT 
locations.id,
SQRT(
   POW(111.2 * (latitude1 - {$from_coordinates['latitude']}), 2) +
   POW(111.2 * ({$from_coordinates['longitude']} - longitude1) * COS(latitude1 / 57.3), 2)) AS distance,
loads.id
FROM locations
INNER JOIN loads ON loads.from_location = locations.id
HAVING distance < 100 
ORDER BY `distance` DESC LIMIT 5

The problem is that I don't know how to find loads that start from this region and should be delivered near the latitude and longitude of another location id.

I'm begginer on stackoverflow, sorry for any inconveniece.